# Django view function file path

Tags: python, django

I am looking at the [Tutorial 7 of the Django Code book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html) and I am having an issue with a view function file path that is really annoying me.

I want to use namespacing as per the earlier beginners tutorial. When my `search_form.html` page is located at /src/polls/templates/polls/search_form.html the below view function does not work when I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/search-form/`I get a Django error saying

`TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/search-form/`

(views.py is located at src/polls/views.py)

```
def search_form(request):
    return render(request, 'search_form.html')
```

**However if I move the search_form.html page up one level to src/polls/templates/search_form.html then the above code does work**. Wanting to keep my origional file structure, I amended the view function to the below and moved the search_form.html back to it original location /src/polls/templates/polls/search_form.html.

```
def search_form(request):
    return render(request, 'polls/search_form.html')
```

I thought this was just a simple matter but I have tried many combinations of file path etc and I just cant see why the file path in my second view function will not work.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks

**EDIT: This is the Template_Dirs part of my settings file**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( '/Users/username/Dropbox/workspace/experiment/src/templates/')
```

I should probably have mentioned that my polls app is a contained within another app called experiment.

Comment: Can you paste your `settings.py`? Or even just the part regarding template dirs.

Comment: Quick question: is there a `search_form.html` file in your `src/templates` directory (i.e. outside of your polls app)? Maybe used for a different view or something? Also, why do you have a `polls` directory within your `polls/templates` directory? Shouldn't the only templates within your `polls/templates` directory be those related to polls? I could understand if this was in your `src/templates` directory, as then you would want to specify the app.

Comment: @Alex "is there a search_form.html file in your src/templates directory (i.e. outside of your polls app)? Maybe used for a different view or something?" No there is not.

Comment: regarding the file path for polls/templates/polls i followed the instructions regarding namespacing in the beginner tutorials https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/